# Script php para recibir datos wifi

Tags: php, mysql, http-get

Tengo una mota sensora wifi (CC3200 de texas instruments) y quiero enviar los datos via wifi a una base de datos `MySQL` local (PC local).

La mota sensora está configurada como cliente `http`.

En el PC tengo instalado `XAMPP`, la base de datos ya desarrollada, un `Script PHP` (`servidor.php`) que sirve de puerta de entrada de los datos de la mota.

Pongo dicho `Script` a continuación:

```
<?php

//incluimos el script insertarbd.php donde tenemos la función crear_base_datos()    
include 'insertarbd.php';
//incluimos el script de emergencias.php
include 'emergencias.php';

//Cogemos de la url el valor de los sensores enviados por el PIC mediante $_GET
@$buffer=$_GET["value"];
//@$buffer=$_POST["value"];

//Llamamos a la función crear_base_datos que se va encargar de almacenar en la base 
//de datos los valores de los sensores
crear_base_datos($buffer);

//llamamos a la función de emergencias
//emergencias();

//Almacenamos los datos en un fichero de texto (Opcional)
$DescriptorFichero = fopen("fichero_prueba.txt","w"); 

//Escribimos la primera línea dentro de él 
fputs($DescriptorFichero,$buffer); 

//Cerramos el fichero 
fclose($DescriptorFichero); 

?>
```

En un proyecto anterior todo esto me funcionaba, pero ahora he cambiado de mota sensora y al realizar el envío de datos me ocurre lo siguiente (según la captura con `Wireshark`):

> ```
> **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**
> ```

Mis preguntas son:

- **¿Se ha de poner el directorio en el mensaje `"GET"`?** Es decir tengo que hacer un `GET` con `"/servidor.php?value=123456\n"` ó ¿tengo qué incluir el directorio `"/xampp/htdocs.../servidor.php?value=123456"`?
- **¿Hay algún problema para que se produzca esta conexión entre la mota sensora y la base de datos mediante un `Script PHP` que no haya tenido en cuenta?**

Comment: No se si lo he entendido bien del todo pero las ruta de llamada via GET sera IP:puerto/servidor.php?value=123456  Las rutas internas solo las gestiona el servidor, no son validas para el exterior.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general tu servidor local (`xampp`) va ha estar escuchando el `puerto 80` y redirigirá las peticiones a uno de los siguientes directorios **`\\xampp`** o **`\\htdocs`** este se tomará como directorio raíz del sitio. Si no se especifica ninguna ruta o archivo por lo general apache entregara el archivo `index.html`, `index.php`... Según la configuración.

Debes de configurar una `IP` estática para la `LAN` en la maquina que haga de `servidor` para evitar problemas al acceder desde otras máquinas de la red `LAN`.

Una vez hecho esto deberás apuntar desde las máquinas que quieras acceder a dicha `IP`.

Ejemplo, asumiendo que la `IP` del servidor es `192.168.1.10` y que el `Script PHP` que queremos acceder se llama **`servidor.php`** y esta en el directorio raíz.

```
http://192.168.1.10/servidor.php
```